Post-hoc tests for a Generalized Linear Mixed Effects Model
This question is linked to this one.
I wanted to know whether the application of a treatment would have a significant effect on the proportion between healthy leaves and infected leaves. I have the following dataset:
'data.frame':   2645 obs. of  16 variables:
 $ ID_pianta                : Factor w/ 478 levels "_Pianta_10S1C",..: 127 259 391 415 427 439 451 463 475 9 ...
 $ Data_rilievo             : Factor w/ 7 levels "0","16","22",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Coltura                  : chr  "Spinacio" "Spinacio" "Spinacio" "Spinacio" ...
 $ Nome_parcella            : chr  "S3C" "S3C" "S3C" "S3C" ...
 $ Blocco                   : Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","3": 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Trattamento              : Factor w/ 4 levels "Controllo","Lavanda",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Infestate                : num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 ...
 $ Totale_foglie            : num  5 5 5 4 6 3 5 9 6 6 ...
 $ Numero_foglie_minate     : num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 3 0 ...
 $ Percentuale_foglie_minate: num  0 0.2 0 0 0 ...
 $ N_mine_serpentina        : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ N_mine_macchia           : num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 3 0 ...
 $ Totale mine              : num  0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 3 0 ...
 $ Note                     : chr  NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Operatore                : chr  "Chiara" "Chiara" "Chiara" "Chiara" ...
 $ Foglie_sane              : num  5 4 5 4 6 2 5 9 3 6 ...

My dependent variables are number of infested leaves (Numero_foglie_minate) and healthy leaves (Foglie_sane). I have repeated samplings on the same plants through time (Data_rilievo), 4 treatments (Trattamento) and 3 blocks (Blocco) per treatment.
I applied the following model and got the following results
model_interazione_ <- glmer(cbind(Numero_foglie_minate, Foglie_sane) ~
     Trattamento*Data_rilievo + Blocco + (1 | ID_pianta),
     data = data_infestate, family=binomial, 
     glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", 
                  optCtrl = list(maxfun = 100000)))

Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
 Family: binomial  ( logit )
Formula: cbind(Numero_foglie_minate, Foglie_sane) ~ Trattamento * 
   Data_rilievo +      Blocco + (1 | ID_pianta)
   Data: data_infestate
Control: glmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", 
            optCtrl = list(maxfun = 1e+05))

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
  4070.8   4253.1  -2004.4   4008.8     2614 

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-1.6316 -0.4806 -0.3263  0.1601  4.4388 

Random effects:
 Groups    Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 ID_pianta (Intercept) 1.313    1.146   
Number of obs: 2645, groups:  ID_pianta, 478

Fixed effects:
                                     Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)                         -2.946496   0.225237 -13.082  < 2e-16 ***
TrattamentoLavanda                  -0.367159   0.290327  -1.265  0.20600    
TrattamentoRosmarino                -0.229678   0.285913  -0.803  0.42179    
TrattamentoTimo                     -0.761733   0.306469  -2.486  0.01294 *  
Data_rilievo16                      -0.001376   0.218749  -0.006  0.99498    
Data_rilievo22                      -0.159527   0.230868  -0.691  0.48957    
Data_rilievo29                      -0.039276   0.223551  -0.176  0.86054    
Data_rilievo36                      -0.437111   0.227087  -1.925  0.05425 .  
Data_rilievo52                      -0.836969   0.234097  -3.575  0.00035 ***
Data_rilievo9                        0.109001   0.218348   0.499  0.61763    
Blocco2                             -0.293182   0.175387  -1.672  0.09460 .  
Blocco3                             -0.008418   0.173219  -0.049  0.96124    
TrattamentoLavanda:Data_rilievo16   -0.018467   0.326883  -0.056  0.95495    
TrattamentoRosmarino:Data_rilievo16 -0.365322   0.353105  -1.035  0.30086    
TrattamentoTimo:Data_rilievo16       0.307757   0.342713   0.898  0.36918    
TrattamentoLavanda:Data_rilievo22    0.021820   0.341668   0.064  0.94908    
TrattamentoRosmarino:Data_rilievo22 -0.220735   0.361456  -0.611  0.54141    
TrattamentoTimo:Data_rilievo22       1.006793   0.335321   3.002  0.00268 ** 
TrattamentoLavanda:Data_rilievo29   -0.069298   0.336827  -0.206  0.83699    
TrattamentoRosmarino:Data_rilievo29 -0.688493   0.378479  -1.819  0.06890 .  
TrattamentoTimo:Data_rilievo29       0.569441   0.337165   1.689  0.09124 .  
TrattamentoLavanda:Data_rilievo36    0.031259   0.348218   0.090  0.92847    
TrattamentoRosmarino:Data_rilievo36 -0.318970   0.379475  -0.841  0.40060    
TrattamentoTimo:Data_rilievo36       0.657747   0.349203   1.884  0.05962 .  
TrattamentoLavanda:Data_rilievo52   -0.043111   0.362318  -0.119  0.90529    
TrattamentoRosmarino:Data_rilievo52  0.176149   0.373696   0.471  0.63738    
TrattamentoTimo:Data_rilievo52       0.954143   0.345730   2.760  0.00578 ** 
TrattamentoLavanda:Data_rilievo9    -0.348574   0.333931  -1.044  0.29655    
TrattamentoRosmarino:Data_rilievo9  -0.135278   0.344355  -0.393  0.69443    
TrattamentoTimo:Data_rilievo9        0.217121   0.342097   0.635  0.52564    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation matrix not shown by default, as p = 30 > 12.
Use print(x, correlation=TRUE)  or
    vcov(x)        if you need it

The results suggest that a treatment (Timo), some sampling dates and some interactions among treatment and sampling dates are significant. I plotted simulated residuals using the package DHARMa and everything seems ok. I then wanted to perform a post-hoc test using this code:
emmeans_interazione_ <- emmeans(model_interazione_, 
                              ~ Trattamento | Data_rilievo)
        summary(emmeans_interazione_)
        pairs(emmeans_interazione_, adjust = "tukey")

and got the following:
summary(emmeans_interazione_)
Data_rilievo = 0:
 Trattamento emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Controllo    -3.05 0.200 Inf     -3.44     -2.65
 Lavanda      -3.41 0.217 Inf     -3.84     -2.99
 Rosmarino    -3.28 0.211 Inf     -3.69     -2.86
 Timo         -3.81 0.238 Inf     -4.27     -3.34

Data_rilievo = 16:
 Trattamento emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Controllo    -3.05 0.192 Inf     -3.42     -2.67
 Lavanda      -3.43 0.204 Inf     -3.83     -3.03
 Rosmarino    -3.64 0.251 Inf     -4.14     -3.15
 Timo         -3.50 0.207 Inf     -3.91     -3.10

Data_rilievo = 22:
 Trattamento emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Controllo    -3.21 0.206 Inf     -3.61     -2.80
 Lavanda      -3.55 0.215 Inf     -3.97     -3.13
 Rosmarino    -3.66 0.251 Inf     -4.15     -3.16
 Timo         -2.96 0.178 Inf     -3.31     -2.61

Data_rilievo = 29:
 Trattamento emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Controllo    -3.09 0.197 Inf     -3.47     -2.70
 Lavanda      -3.52 0.215 Inf     -3.94     -3.10
 Rosmarino    -4.00 0.280 Inf     -4.55     -3.46
 Timo         -3.28 0.190 Inf     -3.65     -2.91

Data_rilievo = 36:
 Trattamento emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Controllo    -3.48 0.203 Inf     -3.88     -3.09
 Lavanda      -3.82 0.229 Inf     -4.27     -3.37
 Rosmarino    -4.03 0.279 Inf     -4.58     -3.49
 Timo         -3.59 0.206 Inf     -3.99     -3.18

Data_rilievo = 52:
 Trattamento emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Controllo    -3.88 0.211 Inf     -4.30     -3.47
 Lavanda      -4.29 0.244 Inf     -4.77     -3.82
 Rosmarino    -3.94 0.264 Inf     -4.46     -3.42
 Timo         -3.69 0.193 Inf     -4.07     -3.31

Data_rilievo = 9:
 Trattamento emmean    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
 Controllo    -2.94 0.191 Inf     -3.31     -2.56
 Lavanda      -3.65 0.218 Inf     -4.08     -3.23
 Rosmarino    -3.30 0.238 Inf     -3.77     -2.84
 Timo         -3.48 0.206 Inf     -3.89     -3.08

Results are averaged over the levels of: Blocco 
Results are given on the logit (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95 

> pairs(emmeans_interazione_, adjust = "tukey")
Data_rilievo = 0:
 contrast              estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Controllo - Lavanda     0.3672 0.290 Inf   1.265  0.5855
 Controllo - Rosmarino   0.2297 0.286 Inf   0.803  0.8529
 Controllo - Timo        0.7617 0.306 Inf   2.486  0.0622
 Lavanda - Rosmarino    -0.1375 0.297 Inf  -0.462  0.9672
 Lavanda - Timo          0.3946 0.317 Inf   1.244  0.5988
 Rosmarino - Timo        0.5321 0.313 Inf   1.699  0.3244

Data_rilievo = 16:
 contrast              estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Controllo - Lavanda     0.3856 0.275 Inf   1.400  0.4993
 Controllo - Rosmarino   0.5950 0.312 Inf   1.905  0.2260
 Controllo - Timo        0.4540 0.278 Inf   1.636  0.3585
 Lavanda - Rosmarino     0.2094 0.319 Inf   0.656  0.9134
 Lavanda - Timo          0.0683 0.286 Inf   0.239  0.9952
 Rosmarino - Timo       -0.1410 0.322 Inf  -0.438  0.9719

Data_rilievo = 22:
 contrast              estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Controllo - Lavanda     0.3453 0.293 Inf   1.177  0.6415
 Controllo - Rosmarino   0.4504 0.322 Inf   1.399  0.4996
 Controllo - Timo       -0.2451 0.268 Inf  -0.914  0.7973
 Lavanda - Rosmarino     0.1051 0.326 Inf   0.323  0.9884
 Lavanda - Timo         -0.5904 0.275 Inf  -2.149  0.1379
 Rosmarino - Timo       -0.6955 0.305 Inf  -2.280  0.1028

Data_rilievo = 29:
 contrast              estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Controllo - Lavanda     0.4365 0.288 Inf   1.518  0.4269
 Controllo - Rosmarino   0.9182 0.340 Inf   2.700  0.0350
 Controllo - Timo        0.1923 0.270 Inf   0.713  0.8921
 Lavanda - Rosmarino     0.4817 0.348 Inf   1.383  0.5103
 Lavanda - Timo         -0.2442 0.283 Inf  -0.863  0.8240
 Rosmarino - Timo       -0.7259 0.336 Inf  -2.161  0.1343

Data_rilievo = 36:
 contrast              estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Controllo - Lavanda     0.3359 0.301 Inf   1.116  0.6799
 Controllo - Rosmarino   0.5486 0.342 Inf   1.606  0.3749
 Controllo - Timo        0.1040 0.285 Inf   0.365  0.9834
 Lavanda - Rosmarino     0.2127 0.356 Inf   0.597  0.9329
 Lavanda - Timo         -0.2319 0.304 Inf  -0.763  0.8713
 Rosmarino - Timo       -0.4447 0.344 Inf  -1.292  0.5677

Data_rilievo = 52:
 contrast              estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Controllo - Lavanda     0.4103 0.318 Inf   1.289  0.5699
 Controllo - Rosmarino   0.0535 0.335 Inf   0.160  0.9985
 Controllo - Timo       -0.1924 0.282 Inf  -0.683  0.9035
 Lavanda - Rosmarino    -0.3567 0.355 Inf  -1.005  0.7463
 Lavanda - Timo         -0.6027 0.307 Inf  -1.963  0.2022
 Rosmarino - Timo       -0.2459 0.324 Inf  -0.758  0.8732

Data_rilievo = 9:
 contrast              estimate    SE  df z.ratio p.value
 Controllo - Lavanda     0.7157 0.285 Inf   2.508  0.0586
 Controllo - Rosmarino   0.3650 0.302 Inf   1.209  0.6209
 Controllo - Timo        0.5446 0.277 Inf   1.969  0.1998
 Lavanda - Rosmarino    -0.3508 0.318 Inf  -1.103  0.6879
 Lavanda - Timo         -0.1711 0.295 Inf  -0.579  0.9383
 Rosmarino - Timo        0.1797 0.312 Inf   0.577  0.9391

Results are averaged over the levels of: Blocco 
Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale. 
P value adjustment: tukey method for comparing a family of 4 estimates 

Basically, the significance of Timo seems not being there. Pairwise comparisons show just a few significant interactions among control and other treatments.
How to interpret this result?
Why a factor being significant for the model looses its significance during the post-hoc test?
